# Location to put credential file AWS android sdk accessing AWS s3

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I have a android app that calls s3 to upload and download pics to bucket, I have that working with CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider now, I want to start using access key as the credential, in creating the s3client object. 
I know I and hard code the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_KEY, put them environment variable or in a file in home directory.

Since I am going to use the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_KEY in my android app, environment variable wont be available. My question is where do I put these keys so that I can use s3client in my android app. Where does file reside if the app were to go to app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never have you access key and secret key in an Android application, hard coded, or in a separate file.  This is especially true if it is going on the app store.  This is a large security risk, as anyone can decompile your app and get your credentials.

What is wrong with the Cognito credentials you are currently using?

Comment: Once the app is the app store, are you saying Cognito credentials is what the app should use ?, and also is this is the standand way?

Comment: Yes, Amazon highly recommends Cognito as the standard for use in the app store.  The reason is because you can control resource access with Cognito, and are only vending temporary credentials to your app.  You can even restrict access to resources users create (like objects in a bucket) to that specific user ( see https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1OSMBRHZVM9V0/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-3-Roles-and-Policies and previous blog posts along with the developer guide http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/)

Comment: How can i download private object (file) in android? If secret key is not using in android. How it possible in Cognito credentials?

Comment: @faziltm check out the developer guide linked above.

Answer (score -3):

You don't need any special file. Just hardcode your credentials as constants like `static final`.

Comment: I thought that's what you asked...nevertheless you don't have to code your own master keys. You can use IAM keys with restricted access. But if you use Cognito then you don't use those keys.

Comment: I think cognito is the way to go.

Comment: Hard coding your credentials is very dangerous, you should not do this. It's easy for someone to decompile your app and steal your credentials. Using Cognito you can greatly reduce the blast radius and damage that an attacker can do.