# how can download aws s3 private file in android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to download files (objects) on private mode in my amazon aws s3 bucket using my android app. I got the answer where in android cannot use secret key.

[Location to put credential file AWS android sdk accessing AWS s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949924/location-to-put-credential-file-aws-android-sdk-accessing-aws-s3)

So, how can i access private files in android. Is there any way? How will it possible? please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hardcoding AWS credentials inside your Android application is a big no no and a very bad practice. How will you manage their update, what happens when they are exposed? I strongly recommend avoiding it.

AWS provides a way more secure and manageable way for doing this via web identity federation and role based access via STS (Security Token Service). It is quite advanced topic but I recommend to start in [AWS documentation for Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/).

If S3 is the only service you need access to you could also write a custom backend application/broker that would generate signed S3 URLs, your mobile app would call this application and retrieve private files from S3, you would probably need some authentication logic there also. Cognito solves all this nicely.